# What was done to this photo to get a surreal tone of pastel-like purples and blues?

Tags: photo-editing, effect

What effects were applied to this photo, and do they have a name?

Is the procedure called something specific? I notice a lot of photos from this photographer have this effect of slightly pastel-ish colorization, in which colors are a bit pleasantly and unnaturally off, but I can't describe in which way specifically.

[image]

Comment: Looks like a straightforward saturation boost to me. Perhaps a boost to the blue and purple channels in this particular shot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like a normal image taken with the subject laying down in the sand.  It doesn't appear anything special was done at all.

Comment: This. Look very carefully at the right (left in the picture) lens of the sunglasses. You'll see a human-shaped thing with a whitish circle beside it. This is a 30"-ish gold reflector, a white balance that's verging on tungsten (with a little residual warmth) on an day with light but nearly complete overcast. The magic happened when the shutter was clicked, not in post-processing.

Comment: @user28116 - nice catch on the reflector, I missed that since I didn't view the image full screen.

Comment: And sorry about the lack of upvote; this account doesn't have that privilege.

Comment: user28116: You should write your own answer, as I think you nailed it on the head. Magic was done in real life with light, not in post. You deserve and up-vote and an accepted answer. ;)

Comment: @user28116 - no worries, this is really a fairly basic answer.  Your observation is more upvote worthy and as JRista points out, you should make your own answer so we can upvote it.

Comment: I see it a little differently: AJ Henderson's answer answered the question as originally asked (after a quick edit of the answer; the first stab was speculation that was immediately retracted); I merely added details concerning *why* heroic post-processing wasn't necessary and moved a comment-in-progress from the question (which, being a "what is this effect", I assumed was going to be closed/held in rapid order) to an existing correct answer when it became available. What's important is that an answer be *definitive* in some sense, not who gets credit. Gamification irks me.

Comment: @user28116 - try not to think of it so much as gamification as it is giving users who show positive contributions to the community the ability to do more.  I cared about rep up until I got to 20k and didn't have any more privileges that would help me help the community.  Now I rarely even look at my rep level.

Comment: No, I insist: after you, Alphonse.